# Integration of $x^2e^{-ax^2}$ with finite limits

Tags: integration

This is problem needed to solve one derivation, so can anybody help me to solve the integration of  $x^2e^{-ax^2}$ with finite limits. The limits from zero to one finite no.

Comment: It's hard to say what exactly are you asking for. Also, we're not community which solves problems for others -- we're here to explain parts that you don't understand. It would be helpful if you could show us what exactly you're struggling with, so we could be more specific.

Comment: Have you ever heard about *chain rule*?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start rewriting $x^2$ as " $\frac{- (-2 a x) x}{(2 a)}$" and integrate by parts. You will stay with the integral of Exp[-a x^2] which is related to the Erf function (the error function).

Comment: i wanted to ask for my help that can't we use log to solve it it will be more simplified i think

Comment: @Akash. Thanks for editing my answer. Using log would me the problem more difficult, I think and, in any manner, we should end with an Erf function

Comment: hmm i haven't studied Erf function yet so i will assume it would be easy